# Generating new type of GanttLink in ganttchart

Tags: pgfgantt

Can I add new link types in ganttchart ? Because I wanna draw a process that starts when an other process sends to him the first input. In addition, processess report theirs ends to others.

The image bellow describe the situation I want.

[image]

I have tried this code but I have no idea how to start a task just after receiving the link

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
    \definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
    \definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
    \renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
    \renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
    \renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}
    \setganttlinklabel{fi-s}{FIRST-INPUT-TO-START}
    \setganttlinklabel{li}{LAST-INPUT}
    \setganttlinklabel{s-s}{START-TO-START}
    \setganttlinklabel{f-s}{FINISH-TO-START}
    \setganttlinklabel{f-f}{END Reporting}
    \sffamily
    \begin{ganttchart}[
    canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},today=7,
    today rule/.style={
        draw=black!64,
        dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 4.5pt,
        line width=1.5pt
    },
    today label font=\small\bfseries,
    title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
    include title in canvas=false,
    bar label font=\mdseries\small\color{black!70},
    bar label node/.append style={left=2cm},
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
    bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
    group incomplete/.append style={fill=groupblue},
    group left shift=0,
    group right shift=0,
    group height=.5,
    group peaks tip position=0,
    group label node/.append style={left=.6cm},
    group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
    link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, linkred},
    link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries,
    link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt}
    ]{1}{13}
    \gantttitle[
    title label node/.append style={below left=7pt and -3pt}
    ]{\quad1}{1}
    \gantttitlelist{2,...,13}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup[progress=57]{\textbf{Worker S}}{1}{10} \\
    \ganttbar[
    progress=75,
    name=PI
    ]{\textbf{Interrogate PI} }{1}{2} \\
    \ganttbar[
    progress=67,
    name=RLSA
    ]{\textbf{Request LSA}}{3}{5} \\
    \ganttbar[
    progress=50,
    name=RLTD
    ]{\textbf{Request LTD}}{3}{6} \\[grid]
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Worker s%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


    %\ganttlink[link type=s-s]{WBS1A}{WBS1B}
    \ganttlink[link type=fi-s]{PI}{RLSA}
    \ganttlink[link type=fi-s]{RLSA}{RLTD}
    \ganttlink[link type=f-f]{PI}{RLSA}
    \ganttlink[link type=f-f]{RLSA}{RLTD}
    \ganttlink[
    link type=f-f,
    link label node/.append style=left
    ]{RLSA}{RLTD}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image] 
Results of compilation doesn't satisfy my aim.

I want to adjust the link from the 1st task to the 2nd, and from the 2nd task to the 3rd task, In which the link starts during the first one and finishes at the beginning of the second one. Also, I want to add one another type of link which starts from the end of a task and goes to the middle of another one.

Comment: Please post a MWE showing what you have tried.

Comment: Please complete you code to a minimal document that compiles.  Also, tell us what you want to try and adjust.